# Too long TextView makes other Views disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, android-linearlayout

How to stop checkbox from disappearing in code below when text in the TextView is too long? I'm not interested in hardcoding max_width for the TextView and I want to display my whole text.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                style="@style/Text"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="@string/multiple_sounds" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb"
                style="@style/Text"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="Text">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/margin</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use weight. Add `android:weightSum` to your `LinearLayout` with value `1`.
For each element in your `LinearLayout` add weight. For example `0.8` for textview and 0.2 for `Checkbox`.

Then set width to `0dp` for each element !

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            style="@style/Text"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/multiple_sounds" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb"
            style="@style/Text"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And update your style :

```
    <style name="Text">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/margin</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: +1 You read my mind, while Im writing an answer :). The point is `<item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>` thats the problem and of course there is not reason to use `android:layout_weight="0"` on TextView

Answer (score 0):

> If you are about to display large data on textview, i suggest to use scroll view in your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late for this but I hope to help smn with this issue. Have same problem checkBox make TextView unreachable for LinearLayout, both checkBox and textView need to have this line in xml:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

### use text view weight = 1 and other view as wrap_content so size of other view not change according your text

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        style="@style/Text"
        android:layout_weight=""
        android:text="@string/multiple_sounds" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb"
        style="@style/Text"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want text to go in new line (use `RelativeLayout`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/checkbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another solution is to use this lib to shrink text: 
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use RelativeLayout to maintain uniformity in UI. Below is sample Relative layout code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    style="@style/Text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cb"
    android:text="@string/multiple_sounds" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    style="@style/Text"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```